# How to set C pre-processor variable from build command lines

Tags: conditional-compilation

I currently build my executable from C source code using these commands:

```
$ autoreconf --verbose --force
$ ./configure --enable-debug --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
```

In one of my C source files, I have this piece of code:

```
#ifdef TESTVAR
#pragma message ( "TESTVAR defined" )
#endif
```

How can I define TESTVAR on one of my build command lines, so that the pragma message prints?  I've tried the following and all fail to print the message during make:

```
1. ./configure TESTVAR=True --enable-debug --prefix=/usr/local
2. make -e TESTVAR=True
3. export TESTVAR=True;make -e
```